# Toggle second class once first class is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

To be precise I have:

```js
$('.vidsh_sub_btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('goright');
  // toggle godown class while goright class is completed moving left to 75px
  $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('godown');
  $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('goleft');
  $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('gotop');
});
```

```css
.vidsubbtn_c {
  position: absolute;
  height: 34px;
  width: 84px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vidsub_rld_c {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  transition: all 700ms;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.vidsub_rld_c.goright {
  left: 75px;
}

.vidsub_rld_c.godown {
  top: 25px;
}

.vidsub_rld_c.goleft {
  left: 0px;
}

.vidsub_rld_c.gotop {
  top: 0px;
}

.vidsh_sub_btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #8495a4;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vidsubbtn_c">
  <div class="vidsub_rld_c"></div>
  <input type="button" class="vidsh_sub_btn" value="Add" />
</div>
```

What I basically want is that `vidsub_rld_c` should complete a circle of the button which basically would look like a loading object.

But the way I have implemented in my script is that when the click event listener is called it executes all of the toggle classes at the same time which makes the loader looking like its not moving.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kto0c3jc/1/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could toggle one class, and use CSS animations to create the effect.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/d3f2pgr7/1/)

A basic example:

```js
$('.vidsh_sub_btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.vidsubbtn_c {
  position: absolute;
  height: 34px;
  width: 84px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vidsub_rld_c {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  transition: all 700ms;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.vidsub_rld_c.animate {
  animation: moveAround 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes moveAround {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: 75px;
    top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 75px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  75% {
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

.vidsh_sub_btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #8495a4;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vidsubbtn_c">
  <div class="vidsub_rld_c"></div>
  <input type="button" class="vidsh_sub_btn" value="Add" />
</div>
```

Comment: thx that pretty much worked. one more thing if you could just make the loader no-stop circle the button that ll be much much appreciated. I tried `while(1)  $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('animate');`  but that make the browser stop responding. don't really now why. but thx anyway.

Comment: I've updated the snippet - is that the effect you want?

Comment: thx u r the best, btw is that gonna make any performence issues?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Maybe this article would interest you - https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/f4jxf79c/2/)**.

You could use `setInterval` to complete the circle by toggling the classes continuously after every 'x' time, like :

```
 $('.vidsh_sub_btn').on('click', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('godown');
    $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('goright');
  }, 700);
});
```

Code:

```js
$('.vidsh_sub_btn').on('click', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('godown');
    $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('goright');
  }, 700);
});
```

```css
.vidsubbtn_c {
  position: absolute;
  height: 34px;
  width: 84px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vidsub_rld_c {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  transition: all 700ms;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.vidsub_rld_c.goright {
  left: 75px;
}

.vidsub_rld_c.godown {
  top: 25px;
}

.vidsh_sub_btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #8495a4;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vidsubbtn_c">
  <div class="vidsub_rld_c"></div>
  <input type="button" class="vidsh_sub_btn" value="Add" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for ur reply but still that toggles 2 classes at the same time, and If I may can you add that on a loop so it just circle the button and do not stop?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery UI so you can chain your class toggles
like:

```
$('.vidsh_sub_btn').on('click', function() {
   $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('goright', 2000).promise().done(function(){
       $('.vidsub_rld_c').toggleClass('godown', 2000);
   });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QajaPm